Fedora kenoite second monitor detected but cannot turn on
I just switched to fedora kenoite. I have a laptop connected to a monitor but only the built-in monitor is displaying anything. When I got to display configuration the external monitor shows up with the correct stats but is "enabled" is unchecked, I am able to check the box to enable it and set the position and scaling of the second monitor. However, when I click "apply" nothing happens and if I click off and back on to display configuration all the changes are forgotten and it's back to showing just the in-built montior with the second monitor disabled.
Please let me know what is happening and/or how to fix it. Thanks,

In this case the solution was to use kscreen-doctor to enable the second monitor from the command line. After that everything else worked perfectly.
